# Why C(m+n, k) can be classified into k+1 types, not k types?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Source: A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates: Counting Strategies by Titu Andreescu,Zuming Feng

I don't understand the explanation in the part that there are C(m+n, k) ways to do and C(m+n, k) can be classified into k+1 types, which is followed by the explanation there are C(m, i)C(n, k-i) $i^{th}$ type  for $0≤i≤k$, not for $0≤i≤k+1$.
Is it just the author's fault of mistyping "k+1 types" instead of k types?
Or where's the type for k+1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $k+1$ integers from $0$ to $k$, inclusive. It is possible to examine $0$ male dorms, $1$ male dorm, $2$ male dorms, and so on up to $k$ male dorms, a total of $k+1$ possibilities.

*Remark:* If $k\gt m$, one cannot actually examine $k$ male dorms, but that is taken care of by the convention that $\binom{a}{b}=0$ if $b\gt a$.